# Pytorch Iterating over dataloader twice

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch

Let's say I have a dataloader (loader) which returns data of the following shape : [BatchSize , 1024]
I have 10000 samples and I want to build a score matrix of the shape (10000 , 10000) such that entry [i,j] denotes the score between sample i and sample j, so far I did it in the following way (setting batchsize = 1)

```
   d = numpy.zeros((10000 , 10000))
   for i, sample_i  in tqdm(enumerate(loader)):
     for i, sample_j  in tqdm(enumerate(loader)):
       d[i][j] = calculate_somre_score(sample_i , sample_j)
```

But this takes a lot of time and i'm sure there is some good way to do it whihc takes less time.
Thanks
Best

Comment: If the score is commutative, you could reduce the number of computations to half.

Comment: @GoodDeeds this will still take alot of time ..

Comment: how much time?   
If the issue is of time then tell us about your system specs. Maybe your hardware is slow.

Comment: I'm using a server with 252 GB ram and 2 gpus , and it still take 200 hours, @Ahwar

Comment: I highly doubt the bottleneck is in the data loading. Try commenting the line in which you calculate the score, then check the runtime. If the process is finished in a reasonable amount of time, you got to focus on improving the efficiency of the score calculation or possibly reducing the number of calls to the score function.

Comment: @MohammadArvan isn't there someway to use bigger batchsizes?

Comment: It comes back to your score function, vectorizing the computations would definitely help. But can you return the score for `batch size x batch size` samples?

Comment: @MohammadArvan the problem is for the evaluation , each sample should be compared to each other possible sample int he dataset and not in the batch

Comment: Generally, you should be able to vectorize the computations while keeping the comparison one-to-one. The only difference is you compute the score in `1-n` or `n-n` chunks.